# Running activity in hidden(stealth mode)

Tags: android, android-activity, hidden

Please can anyone give me links or code or concept for Running an activity in hidden mode.. That is, it has to run in background without disturbing the user.. It should not display any window or layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Activity is always something that is show to the user. If an activity is not shown to the user it is not executing code but will be paused by the system.

You should look into [services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) if you want to have a running process that is not visible to the user.

Comment: does this service class has the properties and functionality of Activity? can we use all the resources and write all the java code and methods in the service? 

im new to android..
Thanks for fast reply..

Comment: And what about when you realy need to instantiate activity on background? For example if you want to perform OpenGL game images pre-loading while other activities are displayed to the user and you can't do it without OpenGL context of the game activity?

Answer (score 2):

Use a service instead of an activity ...That will be better to implement a running process not visible to the user and do perform the work...